# Application.InputBox method in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

Several years ago, using Excel 97, I wrote a VBA program that used the

```
Set R = Application.InputBox( Prompt etc. ... Type:=8)
```

method for the user to select a cell in an open workbook/worksheet. This worked without problems then, but now I am revising the program for Excel 2007 and it only works if the user types in the A1-format address. It does not allow the user to move around the open workbooks and worksheets, or scroll the worksheet, to find the cell he wants.

Curiously, however, it does work as advertised if located in a macro, but only to select a cell using the mouse in the same workbook as the macro.

I wonder if anyone else has come across this issue, and did they find a fix for it?

Comment: Where is the code located then?

Comment: The code is located in an xlsm file that is opened together with other workbooks that it is to analyse. The code is in a vba project in that workbook. I mentioned my experiment of putting it in a macro in a target workbook - I did this mainly to be sure the issue is not with the code itself. Does that make it clear? I may not have understood the implications of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me.  I have never used this approach in Excel '97, so I don't know if the inputbox appears differently.

I have checked it in 2007 and 2013 (placing the code in a code module and in a worksheet object)and the `Application.InputBox(...,type:=8)` does allow the user to select sheets and ranges from an open workbook.

The only difference is that 2007 does not allow the user to navigate away from the workbook that was active when the inputbox is displayed.

Is your problem with extracting the worksheet from the range object?  This can be done using `Set ws = r.Worksheet` or `sheetName = r.Worksheet.Name`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To the last paragraph: No - my only problem is getting the range object by clicking on the cell in the (other) open workbook. Since user has already selected the wb and ws from lists (I put this is because I cannot get him there with the mouse) I will try activating same before calling the InputBox method, but I am pretty sure that I already tried this some time ago. Many thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I tried activating the ws but it does not appear - not at least until the whole procedure ends, long after I wanted to select the cell with the mouse. I have gone back to selecting with the A1 address.